# python java Tika urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: c>

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error, urllib, apache-tika, pdf-parsing

<<<fixed by getting Tika 1.25 .jar files and changing the TIKA_SERVER_JAR environment variable to file:\\C:\CODING\Apache Tika\tika-server-1.25.jar thanks to all involved>>>
I saw this thread [Python Tika error: URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: c>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66330992/python-tika-error-urlerror-urlopen-error-unknown-url-type-c/66609798#66609798)
This same thing is happening to me right now. And it's frustrating.
I made a post in that thread but I was told to make a new thread by somebody in comments. So here it is.
I Googled and looked through StackOverflow but I found nothing that seems on point.

python 3.9.2 (very recent upgrade (say 03/08/21) from python 3.8.2 or something similar I forget)
tika 1.24 (python package)
tika 1.24.1 (jar file (has been working just fine))

1. Originally I had set the powershell $env: variable to point to tika.jar file which was working fine until recently. On startup in python tika would make the python interpreter search for the tika REST api to get the latest parser; so I pointed the $env: variable to the tika.jar file so it would think to search...find the tika.jar file on my machine and use that instead.
2. Now I'm getting this error message below...

> 2021-03-12 18:14:46,032 [MainThread  ] [INFO ]  Retrieving
> C:\PATH\TO\tika-server-1.24.1.jar to
> C:\PATH\TO\Local\Temp\tika-server.jar. Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File
> "C:\CODING\Python392\lib\site-packages\tika\tika.py", line 798, in
> getRemoteJar
> urlretrieve(urlOrPath, destPath)   File "C:\CODING\Python392\lib\urllib\request.py", line 239, in urlretrieve
> with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:   File "C:\CODING\Python392\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
> return opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File "C:\CODING\Python392\lib\urllib\request.py", line 517, in open
> response = self._open(req, data)   File "C:\CODING\Python392\lib\urllib\request.py", line 539, in _open
> return self._call_chain(self.handle_open, 'unknown',   File "C:\CODING\Python392\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
> result = func(*args)   File "C:\CODING\Python392\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1417, in
> unknown_open
> raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type) urllib.error.URLError:
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:\PATH\TO#tika test.py", line 75, in 
> TIKA_FUNCTION(folder)   File "c:\PATH\TO#tika test.py", line 38, in TIKA_FUNCTION
> rawtext = parser.from_file(filename)   File "C:\CODING\Python392\lib\site-packages\tika\parser.py", line 40, in
> from_file
> output = parse1(service, filename, serverEndpoint, headers=headers, config_path=config_path,
> requestOptions=requestOptions)   File
> "C:\CODING\Python392\lib\site-packages\tika\tika.py", line 336, in
> parse1
> status, response = callServer('put', serverEndpoint, service, f,   File "C:\CODING\Python392\lib\site-packages\tika\tika.py", line 531,
> in callServer
> serverEndpoint = checkTikaServer(scheme, serverHost, port, tikaServerJar, classpath, config_path)   File
> "C:\CODING\Python392\lib\site-packages\tika\tika.py", line 592, in
> checkTikaServer
> getRemoteJar(tikaServerJar, jarPath)   File "C:\CODING\Python392\lib\site-packages\tika\tika.py", line 808, in
> getRemoteJar
> urlretrieve(urlOrPath, destPath)    File "C:\CODING\Python392\lib\urllib\request.py", line 239, in urlretrieve
> with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:   File "C:\CODING\Python392\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
> return opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File "C:\CODING\Python392\lib\urllib\request.py", line 517, in open
> response = self._open(req, data)   File "C:\CODING\Python392\lib\urllib\request.py", line 539, in _open
> return self._call_chain(self.handle_open, 'unknown',   File "C:\CODING\Python392\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
> result = func(*args)   File "C:\CODING\Python392\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1417, in
> unknown_open
> raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type) urllib.error.URLError:

3. I saw all the comments to the original post. (of the original thread)
4. I changed the windows defender firewall to accept the tika.jar file as per one of the comments.
5. Didn't work.
6. I've been changing the $env: variable to include things like "file:///C:/tika/path.jar" etc (tried both f:/// and f://). Even outright removing the $env: variable so it gets the latest parser info or whatever.
7. Didn't work.
8. I'm trying to figure out what all this is about in this thread https://bugs.python.org/issue6193
9. But this seems to be a little bit of a disparate comparison for my situation because the issue in python.org thread is user asking urllib to open a file in script whereas I am not doing this exactly.
10. Now it's possible that the fix described in python.org thread is over my head with the file:/// command because I'm not the best coder, I'm not sure I understand it that well.
11. In the python.org thread discussion everyone is talking like "just do this file:/// thing" but no one is really explaining it in a way I can understand.
12. There is an inter-thread reference to another link in regards to urllib splittype method, but the link is dead.
13. But it still seems like a disparate comparison because if urllib just couldn't handle opening the file, the whole process never would have worked to begin with when I originally set it up some months ago.
14. Which leads me to believe the issue really is that installing python 3.9.2 and uninstalling the 3.8.2 broke the scripts ability to work. But that seems wrong somehow. (And if it's not, how can I fix it? reinstall tika.jar with Maven?)
15. I suppose it's possible that the default urllib module was updated or something but then that python.org thread is from 2009. It is 2021. In 2020 my program script was working just fine.

My next step will be...to investigate this little...splittype urllib method.

But will it actually yield anything? Not so sure.

Any assistance with reasoning, methods, or code would be appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance.

edit: tika --dump-current-config below

```
Mar 14, 2021 10:15:23 PM org.apache.tika.config.InitializableProblemHandler$3 handleInitializableProblem
WARNING: J2KImageReader not loaded. JPEG2000 files will not be processed.
See https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html#jai-image-io
for optional dependencies.

Mar 14, 2021 10:15:24 PM org.apache.tika.config.InitializableProblemHandler$3 handleInitializableProblem
WARNING: Tesseract OCR is installed and will be automatically applied to image files unless
you've excluded the TesseractOCRParser from the default parser.
Tesseract may dramatically slow down content extraction (TIKA-2359).
As of Tika 1.15 (and prior versions), Tesseract is automatically called.
In future versions of Tika, users may need to turn the TesseractOCRParser on via TikaConfig.
Mar 14, 2021 10:15:24 PM org.apache.tika.config.InitializableProblemHandler$3 handleInitializableProblem
WARNING: org.xerial's sqlite-jdbc is not loaded.
Please provide the jar on your classpath to parse sqlite files.
See tika-parsers/pom.xml for the correct version.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<properties>
  <!--for example: <mimeTypeRepository resource="/org/apache/tika/mime/tika-mimetypes.xml"/>-->
  <service-loader dynamic="true" loadErrorHandler="IGNORE"/>
  <encodingDetectors>
    <encodingDetector class="org.apache.tika.detect.DefaultEncodingDetector"/>
  </encodingDetectors>
  <translator class="org.apache.tika.language.translate.DefaultTranslator"/>
  <detectors>
    <detector class="org.apache.tika.detect.DefaultDetector"/>
  </detectors>
  <parsers>
    <parser class="org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser"/>
  </parsers>
</properties>
```

tika-config.xml from C:\PATH\TO\tika\parser\pdf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation  (...cutout...)
-<properties>
-<parsers>
-<parser class="org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser">
-<params>
<param type="bool" name="sortByPosition">true</param>
</params>
</parser>
</parsers>
</properties>
```

Comment: Can you start the Apache Tika server manually without error? (`java -jar path-to-your-tika-server.jar`). If you go to localhost:9998 after the server is started, do you get the welcome page? Need to figure out if your issue is with the Server itself, or the python client code for calling it

Comment: 2 tika wont run in regular cmd at all (strange)
3 tika runs in powershell fine
4a curl localhost: (7) failed to connect...port 80: connection refused
4b curl localhost:9998 (same as #4)
4c localhost:9998: syntax incorrect
4d ping localhost works
4e ping localhost:9998 couldnt find host
5 on tika gui; Apache Tika was unable to parse the document (on .pdf I had parsed previously no problem)
6 in powershell noticed big warning below which is making me think that I have recently installed tesseract is somehow problematic for tika...(see next comment for warning)

Comment: 6 (cont) warning from tika in powershell:
Mar 14, 2021 2:41:16 PM org.apache.tika.config.InitializableProblemHandler$3 handleInitializableProblem
WARNING: J2KImageReader not loaded. JPEG2000 files will not be processed. (...)
WARNING: Tesseract OCR is installed and will be automatically applied to image files unless
you've excluded the TesseractOCRParser from the default parser. 
(...)
users may need to turn the TesseractOCRParser on via TikaConfig. (...)
(this message on: java -jar tika-app-1.24.1.jar --gui)

Comment: 7 recently (just before I switched to python 3.9.2) I installed tesseract; but now I'm trying to parse pdfs with tika
8 next step is to toggle tesseract via TikaConfig
9 but this still seems inadequate with regard to the urllib issue

Comment: 10 tika gui gives a large error. the highlights of which seem to be: org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: Unexpected RuntimeException from org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser@46f67d15 (...) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: You'll need to fix that Null Pointer exception to have a chance of Tika working - my guess is you've got an invalid Apache Tika config file. Can you post the config file you're using?

Comment: @Gagravarr I can't write a new "answer" but I've edited the original post to include --dump-current-config info at bottom

Comment: here's the crazy thing about this right? unless I'm just doing something wrong when I'm in powershell and I write java -jar tika-app-1.24.1.jar -t Test03.pdf output.txt (...) it prints the document text in powershell and rather than making .txt file prints: Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: output.txt
at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:672)
at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:568)
at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:515)
at org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI.process(TikaCLI.java:488)
at org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI.main(TikaCLI.java:149)

Comment: @Gagravarr i'm not sure I understand how to get to the config file. are you saying the .xml file or the print out I've edit into thread above?

Comment: Hang on - the Tika Python wrapper works with the *Tika Server* not the *Tika CLI App* - which jar are you passing along in the environment variable?

Comment: @Gagravarr I set the environment variable like so: $env:TIKA_SERVER_JAR = "C:\CODING\Apache Tika\TikaPyOfflineConfig-tika-server-1.24.1.jar"

Comment: @Gagravarr I also just straight up removed the $env: variable

Comment: @Gagravarr it looks like Tika 1.25 is out right now; should I get rid of Tika 1.24 entirely, try to use 1.25 instead, then come back here and report progress?

Comment: Yes, 1.25 has a few key bugfixes in it

Comment: @Gagravarr Ok. Will do. I'll come back and report. Thanks.

Comment: #Gagravarr Ok. So. Tika 1.25 works. It gives these annoying errors, but it works through command line. Now when I run the python module regularly 1) it checks for the Tike 1.24.1 .jar file over the internet; fine whatever but 2) changing the env: variable to tika-server-1.25.jar gives me the urllib error again; so im changing the env: variable to tika-app-1.25 to see whats going on

Comment: @Gagravarr if it will let me write this...what I meant to say was "gives these annoying warnings...but it works" so I changed the environment variable to tika-app-1.25 didnt work.

Comment: @Gagravarr fixed. changed TIKA_SERVER_JAR environment variable to file:\\\C:\CODING\Apache Tika\tika-server-1.25.jar thanks for your assistance.